# Behind workings of JPA when assembling objects

Tags: java, spring, jpa, memory, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
public class City {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String country;
    private String description;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<Comment> comments = new LinkedHashSet<Comment>();
}
@Entity
public class Comment {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="city_id")
    private City city;
}

public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Integer> {}
public interface CommentRepository extends JpaRepository<Comment, Integer> {}

@Service
public class MainService {

    CityRepository cityRepository;
    CommentRepository commentRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public MainService(CityRepository cityRepository,
            CommentRepository commentRepository) {
        this.cityRepository = cityRepository;
        this.commentRepository = commentRepository;
    }

    public Comment addComment() {
        Comment comment = new Comment("some description");
        City city = new City("Belgrad", "Serbia", "Noice.");
    
        comment.setCity(city);

        cityRepository.save(city);
        commentRepository.save(comment);


        City cityFromDatabase = cityRepository.findById(1).get(); **//call 1**
        return comment;
    }
    public City getCity(int id) {
        return cityRepository.findById(1).get(); **//call 2**
    }
}
```

When I make call 1 from controller, city object will have empty list of comments but when I make call 2, city object will have 1 comment in his list of comment objects. Can someone explain to me why is that so? 
My guess is it has something to do with memory. When we make first call we already have city object with id 1 in memory, so our persistence provider just return that. In call 2 we don't have any, so our provider must assemble new one, and it do return a object with correct state. But then again I tried to remove reference city before making call 1. I set it to null, then called .gc() and put main thread to sleep for 10 seconds before making a call to repository to give me city object with id 1. Result stayed the same, returned a city object with empty list of comments.